# Looking to implement write timeout when there is a delay in writing message to a queue

Tags: timeout, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We are working on a billing invoice system. As a part of processing our request, we need to make an asynchronous call by placing a message in a queue. We work at 20TPS and have SLA for entire transaction of 12 sec. Occasionally, we have observed that when MQ server becomes very slow but **still operational** it's taking a lot of time just to write the message in the queue. We want to handle this scenario and have a system that throws an exception when it exceeds a predefined limit for writing the message in the queue.

In simple words, we want to implement a write timeout when there is a delay in writing a message in the queue. Any help is appreciated.

We are aware of mentioning timeout for receiving the response but we are unable to find any fix for mentioning timeout while writing the message in the queue.
We have found some suggestions on revalidating the destination. But in our case, we already know the destination is operational and our system becomes slow only during the response.

Comment: How have you determined it is the _MQ server_ which has become very slow?

Comment: The only ways that could work is either to issue the PUT under syncpoint and MQ BACKOUT if the PUT operation exceeds a certain elapsed time. 
The second option is to have the consumer inspect the timestamps of the message and rejects the ones which are stale. Also, consider using MQ reporting so that the producer may get feedback about COA COD Pos/Neg Action notifications and so on ...